# Text in plane not displaying offline in A-Frame PWA

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker, aframe, progressive-web-apps

I've deployed an A-Frame app as a PWA using a service worker. Everything works 100% perfectly offline, except, for some reason the text in planes is not visible unless online.

In other words, I navigate to the site whilst online and it loads fine with the service worker active. I then select "Add to Desktop" from Chrome tools, and disconnect from the internet completely. I then open the app from my local machine desktop and everything works like a dream, as if online, except this text display issue.

Here's an example:

```
<a-entity
 id="sound5"
 position="1.8 2.6 -2.2"
 rotation="0 0 0"
 visible="true"
 geometry="primitive:plane;height:0.05;width:0.1"
 material="color:#C71585 "
 text="align:center;color:white;value:TEXT VALUE;width:1"
 scale="5 5 5"
 sound="src: url(test.mp3); on: click"
>
</a-entity>
```

Any idea how I can remedy?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's a *really* good idea to to avoid excessively long lines of code for readability reasons. I have edited the question to show you what you could do. (See, it's ***much*** easier to read now!). It's also a good idea to take the [Tour] and read the [ask] page.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There seems to be a typo where you said ***"the text in planes is not visible*** unless ***online"***. Did you mean "if" instead of "unless"?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the edits. I've tried to edit to make the question even more clear. Nope, displays fine whilst online

Comment: Much clearer now! (Should have paid more attention to the title. It clearly describes the problem.) Unfortunately, I haven't used A-Frame so I can't help with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cache the font and font images: https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/text.html#stock-fonts

For example:

- https://cdn.aframe.io/fonts/Roboto-msdf.json
- https://cdn.aframe.io/fonts/Roboto-msdf.png

for the default font.

Comment: Thanks very much Kevin, didn't realize that.